# Element API locale

Tags: localization, plugin-elementapi

Is it possible to get the right locale based on url? For instance 
`http://example.com/entries.json` gives english content while `http://example.com/no/entries.json` gives norwegian content? Or can I somehow specify different locales in `criteria` or some other option, per endpoint in `elementapi.php`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I had the same problem lately and solved it with a `locale` query parameter.

The code for this inside `craft/config/elementapi.php` looks like this:

```
return [
    'endpoints' => function () {
        'entries.json' => function () {
            // Get the `locale` query param and fallback to
            // current locale if not defined.
            $locale = craft()->request->getQuery('locale', craft()->getLanguage());

            return [
                'elementType' => 'Entry',
                'criteria' => [
                    'section' => 'myEntries',
                    'locale' => $locale
                ],
                'transformer' => new EntriesTransformer()
            ];
        }
    }
];
```

If you want to use static translations or formatted dates inside your `transformer` you will need to specify the locale for that too. Look at [Modify Craft locale inside Element API plugin?](https://craftcms.stackexchange.com/questions/16653/modify-craft-locale-inside-element-api-plugin) for a possible solutions.