# Modify Craft locale inside Element API plugin?

Tags: plugin-development, localization, plugin-elementapi

I’m using the [Element API](https://github.com/pixelandtonic/ElementAPI) plugin to retrieve my entries as JSON. It is available under the `/api` route. For getting entries in a different locale I pass a `locale` query param and use it inside the ElementQuery.

All works fine so far, BUT when I want to use `Craft::t` inside of a transformer, I get the translations from the main locale, because this is where my `/api` namespace lives.

Is it possible to modify the `locale` that Craft is set to, from inside the Element API plugin?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I tried solving my problem by passing the additional parameters to the `Craft::t()` function mentioned by Brad. For static translations this worked fine, but it still left me with wrong formatted dates inside of twig templates, that were rendered by my transformer.

I found another solution to the problem: Setting the current language globally on the craft instance by using `craft()->setLanguage()`.

Now my code looks like this inside `craft/config/elementapi.php`:

```
return [
    'endpoints' => function () {
        'api/galleries' => function () {
            $locale = craft()->request->getQuery('locale', craft()->getLanguage());
            craft()->setLanguage($locale);

            return [
                'elementType' => 'Entry',
                'criteria' => [
                    'section' => 'galleries',
                    'locale' => $locale
                ],
                'transformer' => new GalleryTransformer()
            ];
        }
    }
];
```

If you set the language globally like this, `Craft:t()` works like expected, without specifying the additional parameters.

Answer (score 1):

[`Craft::t()`](https://github.com/pixelandtonic/ElementAPI) has a whole bunch of parameters you can pass into it.

```
public static function t($message, $variables = array(), $source = null, $language = null, $category = 'craft')
```

It sounds like what you're looking for is the 4th one.

```
Craft::t('my string', null, null, 'es')
```

Where `'es'` would be a target locale other than your main one.

Answer (score 1):

```
//get element in the specifict language site        
function langEntry($entry_id) {
    return GlobalSet::find()->id($entry_id)->site("site_name_lang")->one();
}
```

Can replace GlobaSet for Entry, Section, etc